# R: tr function (replace characters)?

Tags: r, string, replace, tr

Any canonical R way to map certain characters to replacements, `tr`-style?

```
tr ('string', 'rst', 'xyz') = 'yzxing'
```

Comment: `chartr('rst', 'xyz', 'string')`

Comment: I hereby accept the comment. Thank you. FWIW I did spend a few minutes searching.

Comment: I found several duplicates searching for `[r] chartr` ;)

Comment: It probably is a dupe, but I remember searching for a long time (more than a "few minutes" and more than once) before finding `chartr`.